# Conditional column based on multiple conditions if row values starts with some character

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe df

```
PersonID  Col2  
220909     100
210900     20
110000     100
219989     20
220877     1009
117777     3000
140000     40909
```

If a person's ID starts with 21, he is a client, if his name starts with 22 he is a supplier , if his name starts with 11, he is a organiser , if his name starts with 14, he is CXO and so on, some kind of mapping is available

Is there a way to map list for df

`if left(PersonID,2)==21 then df['Type] = 'Client' elif left(PersonID,2)==22 then df['Type'] == 'Supplier'`

and so on?

Expected output

```
PersonID  Col2   Type 
220909     100   Supplier
210900     20    Client
110000     100   Organiser
219989     20    Client
220877     1009  Supplier
117777     3000   Organiser
140000     40909  CXO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create a series `p` that is just the first two letters of the `PersonID` column. Then, you can use `np.select` with multiple conditions and results based off the value of `p` for each row:

```
p = df['PersonID'].astype(str).str[:2]
df['Type'] = np.select([p == '21', p == '22', p == '11', p == '14'],
                       ['Client', 'Supplier', 'Organiser', 'CXO'])
df
Out[1]: 
   PersonID   Col2       Type
0    220909    100   Supplier
1    210900     20     Client
2    110000    100  Organiser
3    219989     20     Client
4    220877   1009   Supplier
5    117777   3000  Organiser
6    140000  40909        CXO
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I did it.

1. Created a column 'idigits' with first two digits of the ID column
2. Created a mapper for 'idigts' values.
3. created a column 'Type' using the mapper
4. deleted the column 'idigits'

Code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"PersonID":[220909, 210900,110000,219989,220877,117777,140000],
"Col2": [100, 20,100,20,1009,3000,40909,]})
df['idigits'] = df['PersonID'].apply(lambda x: str(x)[:2])
df['idigits'].astype(str)
mapper = {'22':"Supplier", '21':"Client", '11':"Organizer", '14':"CXO"}
df['Type'] = df['idigits'].replace(mapper)
df.drop('idigits',1, inplace=True)
```